# Artifactory Docker Image in ECS Fargate has bad permissions

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, artifactory, file-permissions, aws-fargate

I am trying to use AWS ECS Fargate to run JFrog Artifactory. I've had it working without any issues in an EC2 instance, but ECS is giving me some problems, I believe are related to the permissions of the Artifactory account that it runs as inside the container, but I don't know why that would cause an issue inside ECS and not when running it on EC2 since they are sourcing the same Docker image. I have attached the logs with the relevant messages here, as well as my task definition.

Things I've tried:

- setting the working directory to /usr/jfrog (did not change anything)

Similar issues that did not help:

- [Same error message, but for the data directory not the running directory](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/144)

```
[shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [installerCommon.sh:1670 ] [main] - Testing directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var has read/write permissions for user id 1030

/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/installerCommon.sh: line 1642: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/test-permissions: Permission denied

[shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [installerCommon.sh:1679 ] [main] - /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var DOES NOT have proper permissions for user id 1030

[shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [installerCommon.sh:1680 ] [main] - Directory: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var, permissions: 755, owner: root, group: root

[shell] [38;5;69m[INFO ][0m [] [installerCommon.sh:1681 ] [main] - Mounted directory must have read/write permissions for user id 1030

[shell] [38;5;197m[ERROR][0m [] [installerCommon.sh:784 ] [main] - Directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var has bad permissions for user id 1030
```

```
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "xxx",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 8082,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8082
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 8081,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8081
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 443,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 443
                }
            ],
            "command": [],
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 256,
            "environment": [],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "readOnly": null,
                    "containerPath": "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory",
                    "sourceVolume": "artifactory-storage"
                }
            ],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": null,
            "memoryReservation": 512,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": [],
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "petclinic-container"
        }
    ],
    "memory": "512",
    "taskRoleArn": "xxx",
    "family": "artifactory",
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "runtimePlatform": null,
    "cpu": "256",
    "inferenceAccelerators": [],
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "transitEncryptionPort": null,
                "fileSystemId": "xxx",
                "authorizationConfig": {
                    "iam": "DISABLED",
                    "accessPointId": null
                },
                "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
                "rootDirectory": "/"
            },
            "name": "artifactory-storage",
            "host": null,
            "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
        }
    ],
    "tags": []
}
```

Comment: I see you have mounted the fsx volume at `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` but the error is saying it can't access a mounted volume `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var`. Are you mounting that volume to the wrong path? Were you using the exact same fsx volume mount configuration when you tested this successfully on EC2?

Comment: @Mark-B that volume is for the data directory, which is for the persistent storage between instances. /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var is where artifactory actually runs, they are 2 different directories entirely.

Comment: Gotcha. They were just so similar I wanted to make sure you didn't have a typo. If `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var` is part of the container image, then you should be seeing the same error if you run this image on EC2, or even downloading the image and run it locally. There isn't anything special about how Fargate treats the filesystem in the docker image.

Comment: Very strange... thanks! Hopefully I can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was very simple, and related to the permissions on the EFS disk. All of the subfolders were owned by the account it was running as, but the folder itself was not. Running `sudo chown 1030:1030 .` while in the folder I was trying to mount fixed all of my problems.

Before and after:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-29:/mnt/efs/fs1$ ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 6144 Apr  6 21:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr  5 07:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 1030 1030 6144 Apr  6 21:40 artifactory
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 backup
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x 11 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:27 data
drwxr-xr-x 12 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x  4 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:27 log
drwxr-xr-x  8 1030 1030 6144 Apr  6 21:18 var
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 work
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-29:/mnt/efs/fs1$ sudo chown 1030:1030 .
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-29:/mnt/efs/fs1$ ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 10 1030 1030 6144 Apr  6 21:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr  5 07:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 1030 1030 6144 Apr  6 21:40 artifactory
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 backup
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x 11 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:27 data
drwxr-xr-x 12 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x  4 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:27 log
drwxr-xr-x  8 1030 1030 6144 Apr  6 21:18 var
drwxr-xr-x  9 1030 1030 6144 Apr  5 07:26 work
```

Comment: DId you have any other issues, running Artifactory on ECS. There used to be support for on the web but it appears JFROG scrubbed it. Do you happen to have  CDK app you can share?

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me was adding in `user: root` to my docker-compose file.

example:

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  jfrog:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
    container_name: jfrog
    user: root
    ports:
     - 8081:8081
     - 8082:8082 
    volumes:
     - ./jfrog/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 32000
        hard: 40000
```